# Play Framework not Hot-Reloading

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Using the very latest version of the Play Framework (v2.3) on JDK 8 on Mac OS X and IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

While Play correctly recompiles my project source code in the background I never see any change in the browser until I restart the app. I have imported the exact same project on another Mac with all the same software and see it working correctly.

I tried everything I could find online, including run vs ~run and using the new parameters for native vs SBT watcher service. I doubt it's an issue with that as I see lines like this one a few seconds after I change anything in my code:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/patrick/IdeaProjects/play-slick-bootstrap3/target/scala-2.11/classes...
```

Crucially, when I hit refresh on my other computer, I get a message saying reload detected etc.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how this works, but I do know that SBT uses multiple Java threads to detect code changes.  Perhaps there's something unique with your Java setup?  Maybe you're not using the right version of Java?  I'm not an expert in this, but this exact config has worked on my computer and my colleagues w/o issue from day 1.

Comment: are you running the play from the Intellij? I had some problems when doing so (although I don't sure it I had exactly this problem).  If so, try running it from outside the ide.

Comment: I tried running from IntelliJ and from the activator console. The behaviour is the same.

Comment: @JoshPadnick well, I'm running the exact same Java 8 version on my other machine where it works without any issues!

Comment: The same problem here. Running from IntelliJ and from the activator console... Doesn't refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a Mac OS X bug caused in some scenarios where the path that is being monitored for changes has 'issues' with case sensitivity. More information on this issue can be found [here](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86239-os-x-fsevents-bug-may-prevent-monitoring-of-certai)

I ran the find-fsevents-bugs application linked to from the above link and it turned out that my home directory path's case was upper-case but showed as lower-case in the Finder. Apparently, this causes Mac OS X to never fire events for anything under this directory - so in my case, nothing was working. I renamed the home directory to lower upper-case via the command line and it started working.

Hope this will be useful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

so what I have done to solve the problem is:

Stop running in Console.

Go to IntelliJ.

Run -> Edit Configuration

click + button -> add SBT Task

In Tasks: type run

Click Apply and its running like a charm...